# How to display navigation and footer in every page in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

I'm making a SPA. I want to make a separate component for Navigation, Section, and footer. Navigation and footer must display for every page when I go to Home or About page, only the Section should change. I created two components but only navigation component is displaying whereas footer component is not displaying. Please, someone, help me out.

```
<body>
<div class="container">
  <navigation></navigation>
  <ui-view></ui-view>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

Here is my plunker link

[plunkr link](http://plnkr.co/edit/4VJ5vYUcBaDGMsgyVDg6?p=preview)

Comment: Do you know you should accept best answer to make community effective, if somebody searching same problem they will see the best answer first. Please accept one of below answers –

Answer (score 1):

Uncomment footer component link from index.html. it has

```
<!--<script src="footer.component.js"></script>-->
```

Comment: If I uncomment that footer component the page is not loading it's going like infinite loop and it is asking to kill the page. I kept for that reason.

Comment: User different tag name like <footer1></footer1>. because footer is default html tag

Answer (score 0):

You can `ui-view` of `stateProvider`

```
<div ui-view="Head"></div>
<div ui-view="Root"></div>
<div ui-view="Foot"></div>

$stateProvider
  .state('Home', {
    url: '/home',
    views: {
            'Head': {
        templateUrl: 'Head.tmpl.html',
        controller: 'HeadController'
      },
      'Root': {
        templateUrl: 'Root.tmpl.html',
        controller: 'RootController'
      },
      'Foot': {
        templateUrl: 'Foot.tmpl.html',
        controller: 'FootController'
      }
    }
  })
```